# Navbar width could not be changed

Tags: html, css

I am unable to ascertain what attribute is fixing the width of the navbar, so as to reduce it from the borders. The CSS is too big so I had to use [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timetosp/m03vq2ao/)

```html
<nav id="NAV_1">
  <ul id="UL_2">
    <li id="LI_3">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/" id="A_4">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_5">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/about/" id="A_6">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_7">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/blog/" id="A_8">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_9">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/freebies/" id="A_10">Freebies</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_11">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/resources/" id="A_12">Resources</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_13">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/how-to-start-a-wordpress-blog-on-siteground/" id="A_14">Start a Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LI_15">
      <a href="http://timetospare.tk/wp01/shop/" id="A_16">Shop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you mean its taking up too much width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does `#UL_2` have `margin: 0px 543.031px;`? That's where your whitespace is coming from. Removing the margin is enough to make the navbar display as normal:

http://jsfiddle.net/vicvipe/tbq0nhk1/

Comment: how did you catch that so quickly , i had been trying to use inspect elements in devtools but couldn't select the whitespace part ? i am asking so that I can improve this skill.

Comment: Haha it looked like an issue with the margins so I did `crtl-f` "margin"

Answer (score 1):

Line 83 in the CSS.

```
margin: 0px 543.031px;
```

Comment: how did you catch that so quickly , i had been trying to use inspect elements in devtools but couldn't select the whitespace part ? i am asking so that I can improve this skill.